# Set delimiter for rxImport

Tags: r, revolution-r, microsoft-r

I am currently trying to use the rxImport:

```
library(RevoScaleR)
dataDir<-"D:/NYSE/"
mycsv <- file.path(dataDir, "TAQ_TNQ_OPR_DER_ALL_01M_20130403_01.txt")
output<-file.path(dataDir, "data.xdf")
rxImport(inData = mycsv, outFile = output, overwrite = TRUE,)
```

However I need the delimiter on my file is set to '|'.

In standard file read in R:

```
data<-read.table(FILENAME, sep = "|", VERBOSE = TRUE,)
```

I can set the delimiter. How do I do this with rxImport?

Comment: Why do you need to set a delimiter for an xdf file? It's a binary format and the "splitting" should already have been done.

Comment: I am trying to read a text file and convert the file into xdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define the characteristics of your text input file (i.e. csv) using `RxTextData`.

Try something like this:

```
input <- RxTextData("inputfile.csv", delimiter = "|")
rxImport(input, outfile = "mydata.xdf")
```